# Get files and directory listings in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android project and I am trying to get a list of files and directories from the SD Card. It seems to be more a less working except the file name is outputting a load of nonsense and I can't see why.

Below is the code I am using to get the file listing.

public ArrayList getFileDirectoryListing()
{
    ArrayList fileAndDirectories = new ArrayList();

```
final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
{
    File[] files = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        FileDirectoryDetails fileDirectoryDetails = new FileDirectoryDetails();
        fileDirectoryDetails.path = files[i].getName();
        if (files[i].isDirectory())
        {
            fileDirectoryDetails.fileOrDirectory = FileOrDirectory.Directory;
        }
        else
        {
            fileDirectoryDetails.fileOrDirectory = FileOrDirectory.File;
        }
        fileAndDirectories.add(fileDirectoryDetails);
    }
}

return fileAndDirectories;
```

}

Below is the code I am using to set the list adapter

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listView = getListView();

    ArrayList<FileDirectoryDetails> filesAndDirectories = getFileDirectoryListing();
    fileDirectoryDetailsArrayAdapter = new 
            ArrayAdapter<FileDirectoryDetails>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filesAndDirectories); 

    setListAdapter(fileDirectoryDetailsArrayAdapter);
}
```

Below is a screenshot of what I am getting back in the list view instead of the actual file names.

[image: Screenshot of file listings returned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you override `toString()` in your `FileDirectoryDetails` returning meaningful details. Currently you're using the default `toString()`

Or just fill your array with paths strings instead of the whole `FileDirectoryDetails`

Alternatively, override `getView()` of the adapter setting the text of the `TextView` to `details.path`